# JSON decode issues

Tags: php, json

I have the following code:

```
$instance = new riotapi($srg_lower);
    $grab_data = $instance->getSummonerByName($summoner_nm);
    $decode_data = json_decode($grab_data);
    $grab_id = $decode_data->{'id'};

    $grab_runes = $instance->getSummoner($grab_id,'runes');
    $decode_runes = json_decode($grab_runes);
    $grab_names = $decode_runes->{'name'};
```

*Note: `getSummonerByName` requires a name, `getSummoner` uses the ID.*

*EDIT: Heres an example of `$decode_runes`: http://pastebin.com/6h2TX9t1*

*EDIT: Heres an example of `$grab_runes`: http://pastebin.com/V3MNtbFA*

I get values from using `var_dump()` from everything but when I go to `var_dump()` `$grab_names` I get the return value `NULL`.

I understand that this issue might be staring me in the face, but I can't see it ^^; So I am grateful to anyone who can point it out!

Comment: What does `var_dump($grab_runes)` show? Also why are you doing this: `$decode_data->{'id'}`?  I am imagining this should just be `$decode_data->id`. Same thing with `$decode_runes->{'name'}`

Comment: `$grab_id = $decode_data->{'id'};` works perfectly fine. `var_dump($grab_runes)` shows an array, which does include `['name']` Heres an example of `$decode_runes`: http://pastebin.com/6h2TX9t1

Comment: @MikeBrant - Hi Mike, I just tried changing to your suggestion of removing the `{''}` but it still outputs the same result...

Comment: `$decode_runes` already misses "name", please provide an instance of `$grab_runes` as requested!

Comment: @Lewyx added $grab_runes example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for adding the `$grab_runes` dump.  By taking the string and pasting it into JSONLint, you can get a very clear picture of your JSON structure.  And what is clear from that picture, is that there is not a `name` property on the root object represented by the JSON.

The only root properties are `summonerId` and `pages`.

So your problem is `name` does not exist in the JSON structure where you are trying to access it, so when you decode it and try to access it, you are of course going to get a null value.

It looks like there is a `name` property nested down a little further.

So, to access it would be something like this:

```
$decode_runes->pages[i]->name
```

Where `i` is the index of the `page` you are interested in (there are several of these in your data).

Comment: Hi! thanks for the reply. But if people were to change their page name you wouldn't know for certain that it would be the `first, second, third` *etc* page. Would there be a way of searching for it without giving a defined position?

Comment: @user3352340 What are you searching for?  This more seems a problem of your data structure.  You should always make sure your data is structured in such a manner that you can easily lookup the data you need.

Comment: the JSON is from a game api to get character stats and such (league of legends). I had it working before where I would generate a string for someone to set as a runepage name and then I would do an if statement to check if they had set **a** runepage to the same as the string

Answer (score 0):

Usually this means you have a character that is illegal. For instance using øæå will cause json_decode to return null.

```
Returns the value encoded in json in appropriate PHP type. Values true, false and null (case-insensitive) are returned as TRUE, FALSE and NULL respectively. NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.
```

https://www.php.net/json_decode

Comment: Ah you posted some example data now... doesn't look like any illegal characters though...

Comment: indeed! I can't see an issue with the code or the data, but for some reason it just bugs out :/